# method object not subscriptable

Tags: keras

```
def generate_batch_data_random(self, data, labels, batch_size):
        ylen = len(labels)
        loopcount = ylen // batch_size
        while True:
            i = np.random.randint(0, loopcount)
            yield (data[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size], labels[i * batch_size:(i + 1) * batch_size])
```

anyone know how i can solve this? the error shows **(data[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size], labels[i * batch_size:(i + 1) * batch_size])** is not subscriptable but i do not know how to change the syntax to return the index

Comment: does it say what exactly is not subsciptable? it most likely should be either data or labels

Comment: both are not subscriptable.

Comment: can you print(type(data)) print(type(labels))?

Comment: <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'method'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out (based on your comment) that labels are not an array, but a method, so you cannot write:

```
labels[...]
```

This is why error says its unsubscribtable.

Find what is that you input as "labels". If its a method that returns labels probably you have to just write labels() somewhere. Or maybe you are inputting something wrong to your function as labels.

Comment: but when i try to print **data[i * batch_size: (i + 1) * batch_size]** it also shows method is not subscriptable

Comment: check then type(data) if its method, its not an array and therefore you have to check why is it wrong.